# How setuptools builds extensions, where to add a compiler option?

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin, setuptools

I was trying to build `numpy` on Cygwin, but I got a error with `xlocale.h` which is defined in `X11/xlocale.h`. My naive patch was to add this:

```
#ifdef __CYGWIN__ 
   #include "X11/Xlocale.h"
#else
   #include "xlocale.h"
#endif
```

Alternatively I could have added `-I/usr/include/X11` to the `Makefile`, but there is no Makefiles in setuptools and I am trying to understand how it works.

When I type `python setup.py build_ext` how Python builds the extensions?

Comment: I doubt `xlocale.h` is the same of `X11/Xlocale.h`. Moreover numpy is already available on cygwin as `python-numpy` and `python3-numpy` depending on python version. Check on the source cygwin package to look for the installation script (cygport).

Comment: Yeah, it's available, but it's not the latest version, and the latest version does not build

Comment: Have you looked on the build script for hint ?

Comment: Which one? The `setup.py`, yes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know my solution is not good, but I ended up doing this:

```
cd /usr/include
ln -s locale.h xlocale.h
```

Before running:

```
pip3 install --user -U numpy
```

And it worked.

I removed the link after pip finiched installing the package.